Enabling vulkan in Ubuntu 24.04 for headless browser
Goal: We wanted to use iGPU for rendering images in chromium for my application.
About system:
We have a dedicated server with Ubuntu 24 and Intel Xeon processor & 64GB RAM.
More on CPU: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/97478/intel-xeon-processor-e31275-v6-8m-cache-3-80-ghz/specifications.html
More on iGPU: https://www.techpowerup.com/gpu-specs/hd-graphics-p530.c2793
After some research and experiments, we got webGL and some other things working, shown as output of chrome://gpu from headless chromium browser.
But see vulkan is still disabled, so as webGPU.
So we checked my system for vulkan and found that version 1.3 was installed.
$ vulkaninfo --summary
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Received return code -3 from call to vkCreateInstance in ICD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_virtio.so. Skipping this driver.
'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... skipping surface info
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.3.275

Instance Extensions: count = 23

Then we researched about compatibility of Processor with Vulkan.
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005524/graphics.html#:~:text=Intel%C2%AE%20HD%20Graphics%20520,1.2
And then switched to v1.2
To setup vulkan v1.2, I followed this guide:
https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.3.290.0/linux/getting_started.html
Even after switching to vulkan 1.2, we didnt get vulkan enabled for chrome.
$ google-chrome-stable --headless --no-sandbox --enable-features=Vulkan,webgpu --use-angle=vulkan --use-gl=vulkan --print-to-pdf=out.pdf 'chrome://gpu'
[0728/142120.205635:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(120)] Requested GL implementation (gl=none,angle=none) not found in allowed implementations: [(gl=egl-angle,angle=default),(gl=egl-gles2,angle=none)].
[0728/142120.207191:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(166)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0728/142120.214533:WARNING:bluez_dbus_manager.cc(248)] Floss manager not present, cannot set Floss enable/disable.
[0728/142120.218999:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(120)] Requested GL implementation (gl=none,angle=none) not found in allowed implementations: [(gl=egl-angle,angle=default),(gl=egl-gles2,angle=none)].
[0728/142120.220608:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(166)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0728/142120.227719:ERROR:gl_factory.cc(120)] Requested GL implementation (gl=none,angle=none) not found in allowed implementations: [(gl=egl-angle,angle=default),(gl=egl-gles2,angle=none)].
[0728/142120.229458:ERROR:viz_main_impl.cc(166)] Exiting GPU process due to errors during initialization
[0728/142120.328050:WARNING:sandbox_linux.cc(430)] InitializeSandbox() called with multiple threads in process gpu-process.
[0728/142120.332606:ERROR:command_buffer_proxy_impl.cc(132)] ContextResult::kTransientFailure: Failed to send GpuControl.CreateCommandBuffer.
Warning: terminator_CreateInstance: Received return code -3 from call to vkCreateInstance in ICD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan_virtio.so. Skipping this driver.
681663 bytes written to file out.pdf


Some usful outputs:
$ vulkaninfo --summary
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Failed to CreateInstance in ICD 0.  Skipping ICD.
'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... skipping surface info
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
error: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR is invalid or not set in the environment.
==========
VULKANINFO
==========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.2.198

Instance Extensions: count = 20
-------------------------------
VK_EXT_acquire_drm_display             : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_acquire_xlib_display            : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_debug_report                    : extension revision 10
VK_EXT_debug_utils                     : extension revision 2
VK_EXT_direct_mode_display             : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_display_surface_counter         : extension revision 1
VK_EXT_swapchain_colorspace            : extension revision 4
VK_KHR_device_group_creation           : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_display                         : extension revision 23
VK_KHR_external_fence_capabilities     : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_external_memory_capabilities    : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_external_semaphore_capabilities : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_display_properties2         : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_get_physical_device_properties2 : extension revision 2
VK_KHR_get_surface_capabilities2       : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_surface                         : extension revision 25
VK_KHR_surface_protected_capabilities  : extension revision 1
VK_KHR_wayland_surface                 : extension revision 6
VK_KHR_xcb_surface                     : extension revision 6
VK_KHR_xlib_surface                    : extension revision 6

Instance Layers: count = 8
--------------------------
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_synchronization2 Khronos Synchronization2 layer              1.2.198  version 1
VK_LAYER_KHRONOS_validation       Khronos Validation Layer                    1.2.198  version 1
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_api_dump          LunarG API dump layer                       1.2.198  version 2
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_device_simulation LunarG device simulation layer              1.2.198  version 1
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_gfxreconstruct    GFXReconstruct Capture Layer Version 0.9.10 1.2.198  version 36874
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_monitor           Execution Monitoring Layer                  1.2.198  version 1
VK_LAYER_LUNARG_screenshot        LunarG image capture layer                  1.2.198  version 1
VK_LAYER_MESA_device_select       Linux device selection layer                1.3.211  version 1

Devices:
========
GPU0:
    apiVersion         = 4206866 (1.3.274)
    driverVersion      = 100663305 (0x6000009)
    vendorID           = 0x8086
    deviceID           = 0x191d
    deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_INTEGRATED_GPU
    deviceName         = Intel(R) HD Graphics P530 (SKL GT2)
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_INTEL_OPEN_SOURCE_MESA
    driverName         = Intel open-source Mesa driver
    driverInfo         = Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1
    conformanceVersion = 1.3.6.0
GPU1:
    apiVersion         = 4206866 (1.3.274)
    driverVersion      = 1 (0x0001)
    vendorID           = 0x10005
    deviceID           = 0x0000
    deviceType         = PHYSICAL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
    deviceName         = llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6, 256 bits)
    driverID           = DRIVER_ID_MESA_LLVMPIPE
    driverName         = llvmpipe
    driverInfo         = Mesa 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 (LLVM 17.0.6)
    conformanceVersion = 1.3.1.1

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics P530 (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Thermal Subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family KT Redirection (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Q170/Q150/B150/H170/H110/Z170/CM236 Chipset SATA Controller [AHCI Mode] (rev 31)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C236 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family Power Management Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family SMBus (rev 31)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM (rev 31)

$ glxinfo -B
Error: unable to open display 

$ ls -la /dev/dri
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root        100 Jul 22 15:30 .
drwxr-xr-x 21 root root       4360 Jul 26 07:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root         80 Jul 22 15:30 by-path
crw-rw----  1 root video  226,   0 Jul 22 15:30 card0
crw-rw----  1 root render 226, 128 Jul 22 15:30 renderD128

$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics P530 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 driver: N/A tty: 196x60
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,swrast platforms: gbm,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 note: console (EGL sourced)
    renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics P530 (SKL GT2), llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.2.198 drivers: N/A surfaces: N/A

Edit:
System details.
$ inxi -F
System:
  Host: creazilla-x1-heavy Kernel: 6.8.0-38-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
  Console: pty pts/0 Distro: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS (Noble Numbat)
Machine:
  Type: Desktop Mobo: FUJITSU model: D3417-B2 v: S26361-D3417-B2 serial: 52731015
    UEFI-[Legacy]: FUJITSU // American Megatrends v: 5.0.0.12 R1.27.0.SR.1 for D3417-B2x
    date: 06/10/2020
CPU:
  Info: quad core model: Intel Xeon E3-1275 v5 bits: 64 type: MT MCP cache: L2: 1024 KiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 801 min/max: 800/4000 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 5: 800 6: 812
    7: 800 8: 800
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics P530 driver: i915 v: kernel
  Display: server: X.org v: 1.21.1.11 driver: N/A tty: 120x30
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,swrast platforms: gbm,surfaceless,device
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 compat-v: 4.5 vendor: mesa v: 24.0.9-0ubuntu0.1 note: console (EGL sourced)
    renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics P530 (SKL GT2), llvmpipe (LLVM 17.0.6 256 bits)
  API: Vulkan v: 1.3.275 drivers: N/A surfaces: N/A

$ lscpu
Architecture:             x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):         32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:          39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:             Little Endian
CPU(s):                   8
  On-line CPU(s) list:    0-7
Vendor ID:                GenuineIntel
  BIOS Vendor ID:         Intel(R) Corporation
  Model name:             Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @ 3.60GHz
    BIOS Model name:      Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @ 3.60GHz To Be Filled By O.E.M. CPU @ 3.6GHz
    BIOS CPU family:      179
    CPU family:           6
    Model:                94
    Thread(s) per core:   2
    Core(s) per socket:   4
    Socket(s):            1
    Stepping:             3
    CPU(s) scaling MHz:   20%
    CPU max MHz:          4000.0000
    CPU min MHz:          800.0000
    BogoMIPS:             7200.00


Hi @guiverc I've added output of inxi -F to the end of the post. Hope it'll clear things up.

also added lscpu output to futher clear things up about cores.
